# Not able to return JSON response from Spring controler (Added jackson jars too)

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-restcontroller

I'm trying to send list of customers as JSON response, but, its returning with error response as

```
 No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList
```

### Config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "net.ifg.spring")
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    return builder;
}
}
```

My controller is

```
@RestController
public class CustomerRestController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;

    @GetMapping("/customers")
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        return customerDAO.list();
    }

}
```

### Customer class

```
public class Customer {

private Long id;
private String firstName;


public Customer(long id, String firstName) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;     
}

public Customer() {
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}


}
```

### JARs added

commons-logging-1.2.jar, jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar, jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar, jackson-databind-2.9.0.jar, spring-aop,spring-core,spring-beans,spring-context, spring-expression, spring-web, spring-webmvc(all 4.3.9 version)

Still its returning me error response.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Just a guess here but try using an array instead (or wrap the list inside some object).

Comment: Show the dependencies you've added and the `Customer` class as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return a list of object as Json in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746382/how-to-return-a-list-of-object-as-json-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: is it the same problem ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905917/how-to-return-json-data-from-spring-controller-using-responsebody

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin, updated my question along with jar details and customer class

Comment: @razor, the requirement is same, but I have added all possible ways to get the result

Comment: @Aliy add the implements Serializable to your Customer class

Comment: @cralfaro.. No still the issue exists

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: @Aliy just to be sure then, replace RestController by Controller and add ResponseBody to your get method, just to check if works in the basic scenario, should be the same as you have right now, but to check it

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin, I'm using annotation based spring where I've only config

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin, but I don't have any other spring boot jars.

Comment: @cralfaro, its still same, I have replaced RestController  with Controller  and updated my method as public ResponseBody List<Customer> getCustomers()

Answer (score -1):

Add Jackson dependency or jar in your project.

Like,

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>VERSION</version></dependency>
```

Comment: Please note that as of Spring Framework 4.3, the minimum requirement is Jackson 2.6. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-to-Spring-Framework-4.x#third-party-dependencies

Comment: @RoyClarkson, My jackson-databind version is 2.9

Comment: Could you please go throw this https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/023-configure-integrate-gson-spring-boot/ .It might help full for you.Configure your custom customConverters(HttpMessageConverters.class)

Answer (score -1):

If this is being made in Spring MVC then the dispatcher-servlet's xml file must have `<mvc:annotation-driven />`tag for conversion to work.